# Yang-Mills/topological string theory (M-theory) duality

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, topological-field-theory, holographic-principle, duality

It is known that there is a duality between Chern-Simons theory on 3-fold $X$ and topological A-model on the cotangent bundle of this manifold, $T^*X$ (see, for example, the original paper by Witten, [Chern-Simons Gauge Theory As A String Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9207094)).

In [Topological M-theory as Unification of Form Theories of Gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0411073) Vafa and friends proposed a generalization of the aforementioned duality to the following set of theories:

- Topological gauge theory on 4-fold $M$;
- Topological A-model on twistor space of this manifold, $T(M)$;
- Topological M-theory on certain bundle over $M$.

Moreover, it is stated there that there is a deformation of A-model which is equivalent to full Yang-Mills theory.

I couldn't find a mention of any of these equivalences in the literature. Could anybody recommend some?

Answer (score 2):

It's a longstanding hope that the planar limit of $\mathcal{N}=4,$ $SU(N)$ Super Yang-Mills theory on a four manifold can be computed from the topological string B-model on $\mathbb{CP}^{3|4}$ (with N topological D5 branes wrapping $\mathbb{CP}^{3|4}$). Nevertheless the precise identification is still conjectural.

The hope was initiated by Witten in his famous [Perturbative Gauge Theory As A String Theory In Twistor Space](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0312171)
 and further developed in [N=2 strings and the twistorial Calabi-Yau](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0402128)
. The basic observation is the fact that the planar scattering amplitudes for $\mathcal{N}=4,$ $SU(N)$, $d=4$ Super Yang-Mills localize into holomorphic curves once translated into $\mathbb{CP}^{3|4}$; generally speaking, given a Calabi-Yau threefold one can think on holomorphic curves as $D1$-instantons if there are some spacefilling $D5$-branes because $D(p-4)$ brane instantons appear as worldvolume instantons of $Dp$-branes. The introduction of [N=2 strings and the twistorial Calabi-Yau](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0402128)
 is in itself a wonderful summary of the hints that point out the conjectural equivalence.

Another related interesting connection is the equivalence between the $\Omega$ deformation of the topological string A-model and a $N=(2,0)$, $U(1)$ twisted version of [Yang-Mills theory](https://pure.uva.nl/ws/files/3126495/7556_UBA003000218_008.pdf) over the same Calabi-Yau threfold; this fact is known as [Crystal Melting/String duality](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0312022) in the physics literature. With some [ideas](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0512245) arising from this connection, Daniel Jafferis was capable to compute the partition function for twisted $N=4$ Super Yang-Mills theory in a complex Kahler surface in his [PhD thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0607032).

Finally, other hints have appeared in many subtle ways in the topological string literature. A very interesting one was given in the paper [String Theory Origin of Bipartite SCFTs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4587)
 in relation to the bipartite graphs involved in the theory of [The Amplitudihedron](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2007).